# Filter DataFrame based on words in array in Apache Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, bigdata

I am trying to Filter a Dataset by getting only those rows that contains words in array.
I am using contains method,it works for string but not working for array. Below is code

```
val dataSet = spark.read.option("header","true").option("inferschema","true").json(path).na.drop.cache()

val threats_path = spark.read.textFile("src/main/resources/cyber_threats").collect()

val newData = dataSet.select("*").filter(col("_source.raw_text").contains(threats_path)).show()
```

It is not working becuase threats_path is array of strings and contains work for string. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is each row a single word or a phrase containing punctuation, whitespace etc?

Comment: Each row has multiple columns.And the column on the basis of which I am trying to filter has lot of text,punctuions, whitespace etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `isin` udf on columns

It will go something like,

```
val threats_path = spark.read.textFile("src/main/resources/cyber_threats").collect()

val dataSet = ???

dataSet.where(col("_source.raw_text").isin(thread_path: _*))
```

Note if the size of thread_paths is big, this will have performance impact both because of `collect` and because of filter using `isin`.

I'll suggest you to use filter `dataSet` with `threats_path` using `join`. It will go something like,

```
val dataSet = spark.read.option("header","true").option("inferschema","true").json(path).na.drop

val threats_path = spark.read.textFile("src/main/resources/cyber_threats")

val newData = threats_path.join(dataSet, col("_source.raw_text") === col("<col in threats_path >"), "leftouter").show()
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Can you write the code here. On which basis I can apply join,the threats_path has only 1 column.

Comment: yes so you replace "<col in threats_path >" with the column name in `threats_path`

Comment: the rows are showing,but I need to confirm,is it really showing only the rows that have words that are in threats_path based on the column _source.raw_text. Also null are still showing although I used na.drop

Comment: I am gonna use isin.

Comment: threats_path is file, so what should be coulmn name ? non ?

Comment: default cloumn name is `value`