# How to pass dataframe in ISIN operator in spark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, apache-spark-sql, bigdata

I want to pass dataframe which has set of values to new query but it fails.

1) Here I am selecting particular column so that I can pass under ISIN in next query

```
scala> val managerIdDf=finalEmployeesDf.filter($"manager_id"!==0).select($"manager_id").distinct
managerIdDf: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [manager_id: bigint]
```

2) My sample data:

```
 scala> managerIdDf.show
    +----------+                                                                    
    |manager_id|
    +----------+
    |     67832|
    |     65646|
    |      5646|
    |     67858|
    |     69062|
    |     68319|
    |     66928|
    +----------+
```

3) When I execute final query it fails:

```
scala> finalEmployeesDf.filter($"emp_id".isin(managerIdDf)).select("*").show
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported literal type class org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame [manager_id: bigint]
```

I also tried converting to `List` and `Seq` but it generates an error only. Like below when I try to convert to `Seq` and re run the query it throws an error:

```
scala> val seqDf=managerIdDf.collect.toSeq
seqDf: Seq[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = WrappedArray([67832], [65646], [5646], [67858], [69062], [68319], [66928])

scala> finalEmployeesDf.filter($"emp_id".isin(seqDf)).select("*").show
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported literal type class scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray$ofRef WrappedArray([67832], [65646], [5646], [67858], [69062], [68319], [66928])
```

I also referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40468776/how-to-use-column-isin-in-java) post but in vain. This type of query I am trying it for solving subqueries in spark dataframe. Anyone here pls ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative approach using the dataframes and tempviews and free format SQL of SPARK SQL - don't worry about the logic, it's just convention and an alternative to your initial approach - that should equally suffice:

```
val df2 = Seq(
  ("Peter", "Doe", Seq(("New York", "A000000"), ("Warsaw", null))),
  ("Bob", "Smith", Seq(("Berlin", null))),
  ("John", "Jones", Seq(("Paris", null)))
).toDF("firstname", "lastname", "cities")

df2.createOrReplaceTempView("persons")

val res = spark.sql("""select * 
                         from persons 
                        where firstname
                       not in (select firstname
                                 from persons
                                where lastname <> 'Doe')""")

res.show
```

or

```
val list = List("Bob", "Daisy", "Peter")

val res2 = spark.sql("select firstname, lastname from persons")
                .filter($"firstname".isin(list:_*))

res2.show
```

or

```
val query = s"select * from persons where firstname in (${list.map ( x => "'" + x + "'").mkString(",") })"
val res3 = spark.sql(query)
res3.show
```

or

```
df2.filter($"firstname".isin(list: _*)).show
```

or

```
val list2 = df2.select($"firstname").rdd.map(r => r(0).asInstanceOf[String]).collect.toList
df2.filter($"firstname".isin(list2: _*)).show
```

In your case specifically:

```
val seqDf=managerIdDf.rdd.map(r => r(0).asInstanceOf[Long]).collect.toList 2) 
finalEmployeesDf.filter($"emp_id".isin(seqDf: _)).select("").show
```

Comment: Thank you for your efforts but I am would like to see if I can do this with the already existing df as mentioned in the question. I hope you have some solution for this as well

Comment: will look shortly

Comment: I tried it with list as well but i throws below error

Comment: 1) val seqDf=managerIdDf.collect.toList    

2) finalEmployeesDf.filter($"emp_id".isin(seqDf: _*)).select("*").show

Comment: This is the error:java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported literal type class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRowWithSchema [67832]

Comment: Let me get back to you soon, am looking

Comment: You need to make a List. Added to the answer.

Comment: Look at the answer now, added a 5th option that should cover your needs

Comment: Yeah below code worked for me. Can you please update it in your answer. Since I was dealing with long number. Thanks

Comment: 1) val seqDf=managerIdDf.rdd.map(r => r(0).asInstanceOf[Long]).collect.toList

2) finalEmployeesDf.filter($"emp_id".isin(seqDf: _*)).select("*").show

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181200/discussion-between-thebluephantom-and-debuggerr).

Comment: Can you pls look into my other problem @thebluephantom ??

Comment: Off to a celebration, will look at tonight.

Comment: Yes please . Whenever you get time do look into it

Comment: No problem sir / madam.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you cannot pass a DataFrame in `isin`. `isin` requires some values that it will filter against.

If you want an example, you can check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52613487/filter-dataframe-based-on-words-in-array-in-apache-spark/52613575?noredirect=1#comment92161973_52613575)

As per question update, you can make the following change,

```
.isin(seqDf)
```

to

```
.isin(seqDf: _*)
```

Comment: Its little bit complex bro..I have modified my question. Hope it will help you to answer me

Comment: Okay will try and let u know

Comment: Check my code and error finalEmployeesDf.filter($"emp_id".isin(seqDf: _*)).select("*").show
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported literal type class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRowWithSchema [67832]  where 67832 is one of the value in sequence

Comment: Even I tried with converting it to List values as well but same error